# Prove $G=N_G(P)H$ where $H \lhd G$ and $P \in Syl_p(H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Prove $G=N_G(P)H$ where $H \lhd G$ and $P \in Syl_p(H)$.

I definitely need some help with this one. I was thinking that maybe the problem meant to say that $P$ was a sylow subgroup of $G$, that would make this seem much more reasonable. Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: Don't you mean $H\lhd G$?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I meant oops

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group ?

Comment: @ThomasShelby Obviously ...

Comment: @DionelJaime  Why is it obvious? (Sorry to ask, but I think I'm really out of touch.)

Comment: @ThomasShelby Sorry.  I don’t think it’s obvious.  It’s uncommon to see a problem involving sylow subgroups and infinite groups.  We would need $N_G(P)$ to be infinite which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H$ is normal in $G$, we have that $N_G(P)H = HN_G(P)$. We also have that $gPg^{-1} \subseteq gHg^{-1} = H$. Let’s apply Sylow’s Theorem to $H$. So we have that given any $g \in G$, there exists $x \in H $such that $ gPg^{-1} = xPx^{-1} $ which implies $x^{-1}g \in N_G(P)$ and so $g \in xN_G(P)$. Since $g$ was arbitrary we’re done.

This theorem is called Frattini’s Argument and can be used to classify finite nilpotent groups.

Comment: A minor error, I think you can only imply $g^{-1}x\in N_G(P)$ instead of $gx^{-1}N_G(P)$ from your $gPg^{-1}=xPx^{-1}$.

Comment: @Tengu You are correct.  The remains virtually the same though.  You just need to add in somewhere that $HN_G(P) = N_G(P)H$ since H is normal.